# Multiple Switch Statements

Tags: php, get, switch-statement

Okay, I have one PHP file which needs to contain several `switch($_GET[''])` statements. For example: `switch($_GET['id'])`, `switch($_GET['open'])`, `switch($_GET['number'])`... Do I have to close it like:

```
switch($_GET['id'])
{

}
```

Or:

```
switch($_GET['open'])
{

};
```

One below another with or without semicolon?

This is my index.php:

It does not fully work. My php file is like this (Index.php):

```
<?php
// THE MAIN SITE
switch($_GET['open'])
{
    default: include("Home-Page.php");
    case 'Site': include("LetsStart/Pages/Home.php"); break;
    case 'Links: switch ($_GET['topics'])
    {
        default: include("LetsStart/Pages/Links.php"); break;
        case 'Tourism': include("LetsStart/Pages/Tourism.php"); break;
        case 'Finance': include("LetsStart/Pages/Finance.php"); break;
        case 'Health Care': include("LetsStart/Pages/HealthCare.php"); break;
    }
    break;
    case 'About Us': switch ($_GET['details'])
    {
        default: include("LetsStart/Pages/AboutUs.php"); break;
        case 'What We Do': include("LetsStart/Pages/WWD.php"); break;
        case 'Our History': include("LetsStart/Pages/OurHistory.php"); break;
    }
    break;
}
// ENCYCLOPEDIA
switch($_GET['letter'])
{
    case 'B': switch($_GET['term'])
    {
        default: include("LetsStart/Pages/TheEncyclopedia/Letter-B-Main.php"); break;
        case 'Term 1': include("LetsStart/Pages/TheEncyclopedia/B/1.php"); break;
        case 'Term 2': include("LetsStart/Pages/TheEncyclopedia/B/2.php"); break;
        case 'Term 2': include("LetsStart/Pages/TheEncyclopedia/B/3.php"); break;
    }
    break;
}
?>
```

It keeps loading my home page and the first page from the second switch.

Comment: no semicolon needed. http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: no need semicolon at the end http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a semicolon after the closing bracket of a switch statement (same as an if statement).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need semicolon, because the `$_GET['id']` is a variable, not a string. Read this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp

Comment: Oke, I have seen. try to place the 'default' in the last of case @Dejan.

Comment: Same thing. I clicked at the Letter B (/?letter=B) and it led me straight back to the home page.

Comment: you need add single quote for this line  case 'Links: switch ($_GET['topics']) to be  case 'Links': switch ($_GET['topics'])

Comment: Done... Didn’t fix it. `Index.php` with two or more `Switch($_GET[''])` simply won’t work.